# Is an AppImage File/ Programme meant to be standalone?

Tags: appimage

I've downloaded a dropbox encryption programme called Cryptomator which works great...

I'm using Ubuntu and I am trying to install this programme on my machine the file that I've been able to get working is an AppImage file.

https://cryptomator.org/downloads/#linuxDownload

Every time I run this programme (or "AppImage") it loads the programme and works as expected - but - it is NOT installed to the machine, rather, it just floats there and disappears on log out or reboot.

Is that the anticipated behavior of such programmes that are created within an "AppImage"?

Thanks..

Comment: In fact, I am pretty sure that I am correct, i.e. that any AppImage is a standalone package that you execute on every occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppImages are single-file applications that run on most Linux distributions. Download an application, make it executable, and run! No need to install.

Unlike other applications, AppImages do not need to be installed before they can be used. However, they need to be marked as executable before they can be run. This is a Linux security feature.

Download the Cryptomator AppImage and make it executable using your file manager as shown at https://discourse.appimage.org/t/how-to-run-an-appimage/80 or by entering the following command (ONCE) in a terminal:

```
chmod a+x ./cryptomator-*.AppImage
```

As long as you don't delete that file, you can run it as often as you like, by double-clicking its icon or by running in a terminal:

```
./cryptomator-*.AppImage
```

Comment: wrong that wont run it